# getText(R.string.really).tostring() doesn't work in a Toast

Tags: android, toast

I'm a little bit speechless.
I have activity A and B.
When I'm in B and get the method `deleteItemOption( much input )` then the Toast crashes my app :D

if I open the method in activity A everything is fine.
But I need the method in activity A and B, so I programmed the methode global but the Toast is a little bit nasty :D

in the `.setpositiveButton` there is a Toast.
Why does the Toast crash my App if there stands:

```
Toast.makeText(context, getText(R.string.deleted).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or:

```
Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.deleted), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but this works:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

EDIT: also I found out that this works:

```
public void deleteItemOption(.... ,final String toast2, ....){
...
    Toast.makeText(context, toast2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
...
}
```

I get my context from there:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.deleteHersteller:
                ListView listViewDelete = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewHersteller);
                String toast2 = getText(R.string.deleteSuccesfully).toString();
                deleteItemOption(Hersteller.this, listViewDelete, getText(R.string.takeHersteller).toString(), toast2 , mainFolder, getText(R.string.hersteller).toString(), getText(R.string.really).toString());
                return true;
        }
        return true;
```

The code in Class A:

```
public void deleteItemOption(final Context context, ListView listView, String toast, final String folder, final String title, final String really){
        Toast.makeText(context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final ListView listViewDelete = listView;
        listViewDelete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                final String deleteName = listViewDelete.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        deleteFolder(folder + deleteName);
                        setContent(context, folder, listViewDelete);
                        //this Toast chrash the app
                        Toast.makeText(context, getText(R.string.really).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //recreate();
                        /* würde gut funktionieren wenn man den ganzen Code überall in jeder activity stehen hat aber da ich
                        global eine Methode gemacht habe, geht das recreate() nicht*/

                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //recreate();
                                return;
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                String titleString = title+" '"+deleteName+"' "+really;
                alertDialog.setTitle(titleString);
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });


    }
```

string.xml

```
<resources>

    <string name="deleteGeschoss">Geschoss löschen</string>
    <string name="deleteGeschossQuestion">Geschoss wirklich löschen?</string>
    <string name="deleted">Löschen erfolgreich</string>

</resources>
```

There is the Logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.niklas.wiederladen, PID: 1549
>                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                         at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:86)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:74)
>                                                                                         at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:377)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.example.myname.myappname.Hersteller$4$2.onClick(Hersteller.java:251)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:153)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)

Comment: the string is defined at string.xml, i forgot to write this ^_^

Comment: Where are you passing in your `Context` from? It's null.

Comment: i put it above in where i get my context from.
`Hersteller.this` is the name of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Toast.makeText(context, R.string.deleted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The documentation on [Toast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) says that you can pass in the resId directly instead of calling `getString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.your_string);
```

Be sure that `your_string` is defined in your `stirng.xml` file

Comment: yeah the string is defined at string.xml, i forgot to write this ^_^ 

it did'nt work, same Logcat error

Comment: Can you tell me which line of code is the error reffering too from your Logcat? Can you also share your string.xml?

Comment: also check my edited answer .. use getString() instead getText() .. if its still null, than something's wrong in your string.xml

Comment: I do not know what you mean with the "which line of code is the error reffering too from your Logcat"

I think the Problem is something with the `final` decleration of the String. look at my EDIT